# How can I modify Graphite Python chart app to accept POST data, not url query parameters?

Tags: post, graphite

I'm using the Python based Graphite chart rendering system to create charts:

Data is sent to the server and can be used to render charts.

The system uses GET urls to render charts:

```
http://MYIP/render?graphType=pie&width=400&height=250&target=*.MyData.memory.MemFree
```

I need to send this chart data by POST rather than GET as above. This is because the target query param could become too long for browsers to handle (20000+ characters).

Just looking for some general guidance on how to approach this. I am examining the Graphite Python code, looking for where the GET is processed, but how do I make changes to use POST instead?

Answer (score 0):

graphite-web uses the django framework to handle HTTP requests.  So GET v POST should both work the same.

Except there's a bug in how graphite manages its internal cache -- https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/pull/719

So if you are using a memcached or some other query cache, you'll probably need to manually patch or live w/o a cache.

For reference, the grafana UI uses POST by default when sending queries to graphite's /render endpoint.  https://github.com/grafana/grafana